# Erro em movimentação de indice num array em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, array

Boa Tarde,
No meu código está a acontecer um pormenor curioso. Tenho um tabuleiro de jogo e quando movo a minha peça passando na célula abaixo de qualquer outro elemento, esta para. Gostaria de a fazer passar, dando apenas o aviso, se fosse contra a outra peça.

```js
"use strict"
var player = 'P1';
var playerList = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4']
function main() {

 var sGame = startGame(8, 4, 7)
 $("#changePlayer").click(function () {
  if (player === 'P1') {
   player = 'P2';
   alert('Entrou')
  } else if (player === 'P2') {
   player = 'P3';
  } else if (player === 'P3') {
   player = 'P4';
  } else (player = 'P1')
 })

 createGrid(sGame)
 //document.getElementById("game").innerHTML = tableOfGame; //passar para o html

 /*----Movimento dos jogadores-----*/

 var UP1 = document.getElementById("UP1");
 UP1.onclick = function () {
  sGame = moveUp(sGame, player);
  createGrid(sGame)
 }

 var Down1 = document.getElementById("Down1");
 Down1.onclick = function () {
  sGame = moveDown(sGame, player);
  createGrid(sGame)
 }

 var Left1 = document.getElementById("Left1");
 Left1.onclick = function () {
  sGame = moveLeft(sGame, player);
  createGrid(sGame)
 }

 var Right1 = document.getElementById("Right1");
 Right1.onclick = function () {
  sGame = moveRight(sGame, player);
  createGrid(sGame)
 }

}

/*-------Tabuleiro de Jogo------*/
function createTurtleBoard(boardSize) {
 let tabuleiro = [boardSize];
 for (let row = 0; row < boardSize; row++) {
  tabuleiro[row] = [boardSize];
  for (let column = 0; column < boardSize; column++) {
   tabuleiro[row][column] = 0;
   //playerPosition.addEventListener('click', movePlayer, false)
  }
 }
 return tabuleiro;
}

function jewelsInsert(tableOfGame) {
 let rowA = (tableOfGame.length) / 2;
 let rowB = (tableOfGame.length) / 2 - 1;
 let columnA = (tableOfGame.length) / 2;
 let columnB = (tableOfGame.length) / 2 - 1;
 tableOfGame[rowA][columnA] = 'J';
 tableOfGame[rowB][columnB] = 'J';
 tableOfGame[rowA][columnB] = 'J';
 tableOfGame[rowB][columnA] = 'J';
 return tableOfGame
}

/*
*
*
*
*/
function addPlayers(tableOfGame, numPlayers) {
 let position = tableOfGame.length - 1;
 switch (numPlayers) {
  case 1:
   tableOfGame[0][0] = 'P1';
   break;
  case 2:
   tableOfGame[0][0] = 'P1';
   tableOfGame[position][0] = 'P2';
   break;
  case 3:
   tableOfGame[0][0] = 'P1';
   tableOfGame[position][0] = 'P2';
   tableOfGame[position][position] = 'P3';
   break;
  default:
   tableOfGame[0][0] = 'P1';
   tableOfGame[position][0] = 'P2';
   tableOfGame[position][position] = 'P3';
   tableOfGame[0][position] = 'P4';
   break;
 }
 return tableOfGame
}


function wallInsert(tableOfGame, numWall) {
 let size = tableOfGame.length - 1;
 let count = 0;
 while (count < numWall) {
  let column = Math.floor((Math.random() * size))
  let row = Math.floor((Math.random() * size))
  if (tableOfGame[row][column] === 0) {
   tableOfGame[row][column] = 'W'
   count++
  }
 }
 return tableOfGame
}


function startGame(boardSize, numPlayers, numWall) {
 let board = createTurtleBoard(boardSize);
 board = jewelsInsert(board);
 board = addPlayers(board, numPlayers);
 board = wallInsert(board, numWall);

 return board;

}
/*--------Fim do tabuleiro-------*/
/*--------Posição do Jogador-------- */
function playerFinder(tableOfGame, player) {
 let len = tableOfGame.length;
 for (let row = 0; row <= len; row++) {
  for (let column = 0; column <= len; column++) {
   if (tableOfGame[row][column] == player) {
    return [row, column];
   }
  }
 }
}

function isItAllowed(tableOfGame, player, tag) {
 let pl = playerFinder(tableOfGame, player)
 let row = pl[0];
 let column = pl[1];

 if (tag = "mUp") {
  if (row == 0) { 
   alert("You can't make that move!")
   return false }
  else if (tableOfGame[row - 1][column] !== 0) {
   return false;
  }
  else { return true }
 }

 else if (tag = "mDw") {
  if (row == tableOfGame.length - 1) {
   alert("You can't make that move!")
   return false }
  else if (tableOfGame[row + 1][column] !== 0) {
   return false;
  }
  else { return true }
 }

 else if (tag = "mLf") {
  if (column == 0) { 
   alert("You can't make that move!")
   return false }
  else if (tableOfGame[row][column - 1] !== 0) {
   return false;
  }
  else { return true }
 }

 else if (tag = "mRt") {
  if (column == tableOfGame.length - 1) {
   alert("You can't make that move!")
   return false }
  else if (tableOfGame[row][column + 1] !== 0) {
   return false;
  }
  else { return true }
 }
 return tableOfGame
}

/*--------Movimento do Jogador--------*/

function moveUp(tableOfGame, player) {
 var table = tableOfGame;
 let pl = playerFinder(table, player)
 let row = pl[0];
 let column = pl[1];
 console.log("pos" + table[row][column])
 let control = isItAllowed(table, player, "mUp")
 console.log("control" + control)
 if (control == true) {
  table[row][column] = 0;
  table[row - 1][column] = player;
 }
 return table
}

function moveDown(tableOfGame, player) {
 var table = tableOfGame;
 let pl = playerFinder(table, player)
 let row = pl[0];
 let column = pl[1];
 console.log("pos" + table[row][column])
 let control = isItAllowed(table, player, "mDw")
 console.log("control" + control)
 if (control == true) {
  table[row][column] = 0;
  table[row + 1][column] = player;
 }

 return table
}

function moveLeft(tableOfGame, player) {
 var table = tableOfGame;
 let pl = playerFinder(table, player)
 let row = pl[0];
 let column = pl[1];
 console.log("pos" + table[row][column])
 let control = isItAllowed(table, player, "mLf")
 console.log("control" + control)
 if (control == true) {
  table[row][column] = 0;
  table[row][column - 1] = player;
 }

 return table
}

function moveRight(tableOfGame, player) {
 var table = tableOfGame;
 let pl = playerFinder(table, player)
 let row = pl[0];
 let column = pl[1];
 console.log("pos" + table[row][column])
 let control = isItAllowed(table, player, "mRt")
 console.log("control" + control)
 if (control == true) {
  table[row][column] = 0;
  table[row][column + 1] = player;

 }

 return table
}

/*--------Fim do movimento----------*/

function createGrid(tableOfGame) {
 var table = document.getElementById("gridOfGame");
 table.innerHTML = '';
 var n = tableOfGame.length;
 for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  var tablerow = document.createElement("tr");
  var tableData;
  table.appendChild(tablerow)
  for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
   tableData = document.createElement("td");
   tableData.innerHTML = (tableOfGame[i][j]);
   tableData.innerHTML = '';
   tablerow.appendChild(tableData);
   if (tableOfGame[i][j] === 'P1') {
    var gridImage = document.createElement('img');
    gridImage.src = "./p1.png"
    tableData.appendChild(gridImage)
   }
   else if (tableOfGame[i][j] === 'P2') {
    gridImage = document.createElement('img');
    gridImage.src = "./p2.png"
    tableData.appendChild(gridImage)
   }
   else if (tableOfGame[i][j] === 'P3') {
    gridImage = document.createElement('img');
    gridImage.src = "./p3.png"
    tableData.appendChild(gridImage)
   }
   else if (tableOfGame[i][j] === 'P4') {
    gridImage = document.createElement('img');
    gridImage.src = "./p4.png"
    tableData.appendChild(gridImage)
   }
   else if (tableOfGame[i][j] === 'W') {
    gridImage = document.createElement('img');
    gridImage.src = "./wall1.png"
    tableData.appendChild(gridImage)
   }
   else if (tableOfGame[i][j] === 'J') {
    gridImage = document.createElement('img');
    gridImage.src = "./joia_1.png"
    tableData.appendChild(gridImage)
   }



   tablerow.appendChild(tableData)
  }
  //y.appendChild(tablerow);
 }

 return tableData;
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) { main() });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="style.css">-->
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="position.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Play</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="Home" src="RT-Banner-Cópia.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <audio autoplay>

    <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>

  <h2 class="Home1 Login"><a href="Login.html">Login</a></h2>
  <h2 class="Home2"><a href="Regras.html">Como Jogar</a></h2>
  <h2 class="Home3"><a href="Pontuações.html">Classificação</a></h2>
  <h2 class="Home4"><a href="Historia.html">História</a></h2>
  <h2 class="Home5 Login"><a href="Registo.html">Registar</a></h2>
  <header>
    <h1>Game</h1>
    <select name="sPlayer">
      <option value="P1" selected>P1</option>
      <option value="P2">P2</option>
      <option value="P3">P3</option>
      <option value="P4">P4</option>
    </select>
    <table id="gridOfGame">

    </table>

    <p id="game"></p>
    <button id='UP1'>Up</button>
    <button id='Left1'>Left</button>
    <button id='Right1'>Right</button>
    <button id="Down1">Down</button>
  </header>
  <button id="changePlayer">Change Turn</button>
    
    <h5><a href="Home.html">Início</a></h5>
    <!-- <script id ="js" src="game.js"></script>-->
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As funções:
isItAllowed(tableOfGame, player, tag)
moveUp()
moveDown()
moveLeft()
moveRight()
são as responsáveis por verificar se é possível mover a peça em determinada direção, e por movimenta-la.

Agradeço a ajuda.